# Get single object from MOQ using Unit Testing, Unit of Work and Generic Repository Pattern framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm new to Moq, currently, the problem is when I try to get a collection of the object (eg WebStore) its works as expected,
but when I try to get a single object from it's not work as expected,

could you please guide me on how to get a single object from the repository

```
private Mock<WebStore> _webstore; 
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
  ...
               
    _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();           
    _webstore = new Mock<WebStore>();
    ...
}
```

#### Methods

```
public WebStore GetAllWebstore()
{            
   var webstoreDat = unitOfWork.GetRepository<WebStore>().GetAll();
   return webstoreData;
}

public WebStore GetWebstorebyId(int webstoreId)
{            
     var webstoreData = unitOfWork.GetRepository<WebStore>()
          .Get(store => store.WebStoreId == webstoreId).FirstOrDefault();
     return webstoreData;
}
```

#### Test methods

```
[Test]
public void GetWebstore_All()
{
    //
    var webStoreId = 1;
    var customerName = "A";
    var listWebstore = new List<WebStore>() { new WebStore { WebStoreId = webStoreId, CustomerName = customerName } };
    var webstore = new WebStore { WebStoreId = webStoreId, CustomerName = customerName };
   
   //Set up Mock        
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.GetRepository<WebStore>().GetAll()).Returns(listWebstore); // working

    ...
}
```

```
[Test]
public void GetWebstore_GetSingle()
{
    //
    var webStoreId = 1;
    var customerName = "A";
    var listWebstore = new List<WebStore>() { new WebStore { WebStoreId = webStoreId, CustomerName = customerName } };
    var webstore = new WebStore { WebStoreId = webStoreId, CustomerName = customerName };
   
   //Set up Mock
    _unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.GetRepository<WebStore>()
    .Get(store => store.WebStoreId == webStoreId, null, "", 0, 0).FirstOrDefault()).Returns(webstore);  **//Not working** 

    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you clearly define the list you want to send when mocking your method?

Comment: @HarryCoder i haver define the return value as following :-           
         ' var webstore = new WebStore { WebStoreId = webStoreId, CustomerName = customerName };'

Comment: update code :_unitOfWork definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to be fixed:

#### Mock the `Get` method

If you rewrite your `GetWebstorebyId` method like this:

```
var webstoreData = unitOfWork.GetRepository<WebStore>()
          .Get(store => store.WebStoreId == webstoreId);
return webstoreData.FirstOrDefault();
```

then it become evident that you should mock `Get` and not `Get` + `FirstOrDefault`

#### Use `It.IsAny` during setup

Because your mock does not rely on the incoming parameter that's why you don't need to specify it as a concrete value during the setup.

```
_unitOfWork
    .Setup(uow => uow.GetRepository<WebStore>().Get(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(listWebstore);
```

With this you have set up your `Get` method that it will receive an `int` (the value does not matter) and returns a collection of `WebStore` objects.

The `FirstOrDefault` will be called on the returned mock value.

Comment: Thank  @PeterCsala , by using **bold** It.IsAny it works as expected. 
as following 
`code _unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<WebStore>()
                .Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<WebStore, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<WebStore>,
                IOrderedQueryable<WebStore>>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(listWebstore);`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @PeterCsala's help, it works as expected by using `It.IsAny`:

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<WebStore>()
                .Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<WebStore, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<WebStore>,
                IOrderedQueryable<WebStore>>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(listWebstore);
```